# Como actualizar o valor de uma coluna através de substituição em todas as linhas da tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Tenho uma tabela `i18n` na base de dados cuja coluna `constant` contém todos os valores com o prefixo `lang`:

#### Descrição da tabela

```
┌──────────────┬──────────────┬──────┬────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ Field        │ Type         │ Null │ Key    │ Default             │ Extra          │      
├──────────────┼──────────────┼──────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ id           │ int(13)      │ NO   │ PRI    │ NULL                │ auto_increment │ 
├──────────────┼──────────────┼──────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ type_id      │ int(13)      │ NO   │        │ NULL                │                │ 
├──────────────┼──────────────┼──────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ i18n_id      │ varchar(3)   │ NO   │        │ NULL                │                │ 
├──────────────┼──────────────┼──────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ constant     │ varchar(255) │ NO   │        │ NULL                │                │ 
├──────────────┼──────────────┼──────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ value        │ tinytext     │ NO   │        │ NULL                │                │ 
├──────────────┼──────────────┼──────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ description  │ varchar(255) │ NO   │        │ NULL                │                │ 
├──────────────┼──────────────┼──────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ date_created │ timestamp    │ NO   │        │ 0000-00-00 00:00:00 │                │
├──────────────┼──────────────┼──────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ date_updated │ timestamp    │ NO   │        │ CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   │                │
└──────────────┴──────────────┴──────┴────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

### Exemplo do conteúdo

Exemplo do conteúdo na coluna `constant`:

```
LANG_WORD_JOHN
LANG_WORD_DOE
```

O que estou a tentar fazer é actualizar todos os registos da referida tabela fazendo a alteração do prefixo `LANG` para `I18N` no conteúdo da coluna `constant`, mas até ao momento sem sucesso!

```
I18N_WORD_JOHN
I18N_WORD_DOE
```

## Pergunta

Como posso actualizar o valor da coluna `constant` em todas as linhas existentes na tabela substituindo o prefixo `LANG` por `I18N` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível realizar a operação de forma simples utilizando o [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) <sup>(en)</sup>, que faz parte das funções de manipulação de texto do MySQL:

```sql
UPDATE i18n SET constant = REPLACE(constant, 'LANG_', 'I18N_');
```